# How get admin privileges?

Tags: windows, installation

I have a question and its long time im looking for answer, i wrote a program and i need to know with which installer i can configure Windows 7 to run my program as Administrator? my program will come up with windows starting and i want it to run as Administrator. I included the manifest to my program and compiled it but windows will ask for every time my program want to be executed it would be better if there will be any possibility just to ask once for admin privileges.
Someone told me with an installer you dont need to include manifest to your program and there will be some options to ask just once for admin privilege. can anyone help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow configure your application to run under the local system account. Usually this is done through a scheduled task or a Windows service.

Comment: can you describe more please? i included admin privilege request manifest to my program, but it have problems like, asking in every time and even worse if i include manifest, program does not come up after windows start, but without it, everything about starting is fine.

Comment: The manifest is used to request special privileges when launching your application by double-clicking it (for example). You mentioned you want to launch your application when Windows starts. In this case you can create a scheduled task which launches your application under the local system account. Another approach is to write your application as a service and install it as a service.